# Keep data only with certain words but not anything else in SAS

Tags: string, sas

I would like to search a string variable only containing certain words but not anything else.

The data looks like:

```
Osteoarthritis (OA)
OA (Osteoarthritis)
OA Knee
Osteoarthritis Knee
OA + hands
Osteoarthritis, hands
OA , hip
OA
Knee OA
```

I can get the OA/Osteo with knee in one output by using

`where prxmatch("m/osteoar|oa /oi", lowcase(diagnosis)) and prxmatch("/knee/", lowcase(diagnosis)) ;`

For OA only, I put them into a second output with

`where ((lowcase(diagnosis)) contains 'oa' and not prxmatch('~B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z~i', upcase(diagnosis)));`

But for the data contains both OA and Oasteoarthritis, I cannot think of a way to do it.

So I would like to keep the rows containing OA/Osteoarthritis, or OA/Osteo with knee, but get rid of everything else. 
OA/Osteo with knee is easy to keep, but I am in difficulty to keep those only having word OA/Osteoarthritis. 
The variable is quite long, messy and no regular pattern, so impossible to list those I want to delete.

Comment: Please show what code you've tried.

Comment: I have tried a lot, mainly with prxmatch, but nothing  works. So one thing I can do is to separate OA/Osteoarthritis with Knee in a separate file as `where prxmatch("m/osteoar|oa /oi", lowcase(diagnosis)) and prxmatch("/knee/", lowcase(diagnosis)`. This gives all the OA with knee data. But the other one with only words OA/Osteoarthritis I cannot think of a way to do it.

Comment: The reason for this is to cross check the diagnosis of OA on knee with other data tables. Say the test request data for a person may contain the test on knee, but diagnosis table only say it is OA/Osteoarthritis.

Comment: Show the code you've tried by editing the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how complex your actual task is, but based on the data and stated goal this might work for you:

```
data have;
    input diagnosis $char50.;
    datalines;
Osteoarthritis (OA)
OA (Osteoarthritis)
OA Knee
Osteoarthritis Knee
OA + hands
Osteoarthritis, hands
OA , hip
OA
Knee OA
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    do i=1 to countw(diagnosis);
        if upcase(scan(diagnosis,i)) not in('OSTEOARTHRITIS'
                                           ,'(OA)'
                                           ,'OA'
                                           ,'KNEE') then delete;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

For each record, iterate through each word. If a word in `diagnosis` is not in our interest then delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The codes worked for most of the cases, except some strange written ones.  So in the end, I combined yours and the ones I used in the question to get the results I want, and filtered out the duplicated cases.

Comment: Cool. Good luck @Fred!

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is rather clunky with SAS. A way to do this is to use the index-function. This finds if the matching string pattern is found the the given variable. Note that while SAS is usually case insensitive, string comparison is not. (Hence, the upcase datastep in middle.

Worked sample:

```
data begin; /*Silly way, but works.*/
    words='Osteoarthritis (OA)'; output;
    words='OA (Osteoarthritis)'; output;
    words='OA Knee'; output;
    words='Osteoarthritis Knee';output;
    words='OA + hands'; output;
    words='Osteoarthritis, hands'; output;
    words='OA , hip'; output;
    words='OA'; output;
    words='Knee OA'; output;
run;

data begin; /*This is done purely to ease the comparison below*/
    set begin;
    words2=upcase(words);
run;

data Only_wanted;
    set begin;
    if index(words2, 'OA')>0 or /*select OA  */
    index(words2, 'OSTEOARTHRITIS')>0 or /*or OSTEOARTHRITIS */
    (
    index(words2, 'OA')>0 or 
    index(words2, 'OSTEO')>0 AND /*<=! AND here */
    index(words2, 'KNEE')>0 
    );
run;
```

There is a bit redundancy between first and second conditions, but this should give you a fair amount to work with. 
For more on index see: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212242.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it seems not work. The result still contains `OA+hands`, `OA, HIP`.